# native HTMLElement properties observer

Tags: javascript, html, input, properties, observers

Hope you are all doing well!
I Have a small question that maybe a lot of you have already thought about...
Is there any solution to listen for native HTMLElement properties (not attributes) updates?
I explain:

```
<input type="text" value="hello" />
```

I would like to be notified when something in the codebase does this:

```
myInput.value = 'world';
```

I can know that the attribute itself has been updated with MutationObserver or attributeChangedCallback function but not when the codebase assign the value through the property directly...

I have tried to do something like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(myInput, 'value', {
   set : (newValue) => {
      console.log('value property updated');
      // I can't do something like this.value = newValue
      // cause it will trigger an infinite loop...
   }
});
```

The issue with that is that now the default behavior of the myInput.value = 'world'; does not work anymore and the value is not actually changed inside the field...

I would like to apply this concept to others properties as well like "min", "max", "placeholder", etc...

In summary, I just want to observe some properties without changing any of their default behaviors...

Any idea?

Thanks in advance guys!

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get native [property descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) first. You can get one from element's prototype.

```
const nativeValueDesc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(input.constructor.prototype, 'value');
```

Then you can use it in your setter and getter to reflect native behavior

```
Object.defineProperty(input,'value',{
  set(val){
    console.log('value property updated', val);
    // Continue with native behavior
    return nativeValueDesc.set.call(this, val);
  }
  /* ... */
});
```

Live example at http://jsbin.com/juqili/6/edit?html,js,console,output

To be able to observe already observed element, or just an element with already provided own descriptor, you can do

```
const nativeValueDesc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(input, 'value') || Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(input.constructor.prototype, 'value');
```